# Code that prints only five-digit numbers with spaces

Tags: c

So I´m new to C and have previously been coding with python (on beginner level though). On my course there is this coding assignment which reads "design a program that asks user to input 5 digit number and prints it with spaces". Building tool gives an error saying that there should be "}" before "else" but that doesn't add up since there already is one.

Note: This is the 6th assignment on this course. There are 70 questions in total and very little information to back the coding up, sorry for rookie mistakes

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
        unsigned number;
        char line[50];
        printf("Give five digit number > ");
        if (fgets(line, 50, stdin)) {
            if (isdigit((unsigned char)line [0])) {
            char * endptr = line;
            long number = strtol(line, &endptr, 10);
            int nrOfDigitsRead = (int)(endptr - line);
            if (nrOfDigitsRead != 5) {
                printf ("Number is not five digits i.e. %d .\n", nrOfDigitsRead);
        } else {
            printf("The number you gave is: ");
            snprintf(line, sizeof line, "%d", number);
            for( int i = 0; line[i]; i++ ) {
                printf(" %c", line[i]);
        }
        putchar('\n');
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        printf(" The given number does not stat with number.\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Verify your indentation first, and fix as needed. Then read the code carefully to find opening braces without matching closing braces (and potentially vice versa).

Comment: You should use an editor or IDE that automatically indents code. It will help you find problems like this.

Comment: Notepad++ has a highlighting feature where you click on an opening or closing bracket or brace, and it shows you where the corresponding pair match is (or none).

Comment: https://i2.paste.pics/bda887a9aa4767ce96744b8a0a54e736.png

Comment: Thanks! I´m using Visual studio code but I have notepad++ downloaded as well and it highlighted the problem more clearly.

Comment: Overall, your code is actually pretty good!  You've avoided many of the common beginner pitfalls.  I would recommend writing error messages to stderr: `fprintf(stderr, "Number is not ....`

Answer (score 1):

You didn't close this `if (isdigit((unsigned char)line[0])) {` bracket, as a result `else { printf()...` was nested inside the first **if** statement. Place a closing bracket just after

```
   return 0;
      }
```

This will work:

```
if (fgets(line, 50, stdin))
  {
    if (isdigit((unsigned char)line[0]))
    {
      char *endptr = line;
      long number = strtol(line, &endptr, 10);
      int nrOfDigitsRead = (int)(endptr - line);
      if (nrOfDigitsRead != 5)
      {
        printf("Number is not five digits i.e. %d .\n", nrOfDigitsRead);
      }
      else
      {
        printf("The number you gave is: ");
        snprintf(line, sizeof line, "%d", number);
        for (int i = 0; line[i]; i++)
        {
          printf(" %c", line[i]);
        }
        putchar('\n');
        return 0;
      }
    }
      else
      {
        printf(" The given number does not stat with number.\n");
      }
    }
  }
```

Also, bare in mind that `fgets()` will read and save the newline (`'\n'`) character in your `line` buffer. You therefore print it twice.

As a suggestion, since you are not actually using the number, you might just print it without converting to a long first.

You can use `strlen()` to get the length of the string, which in your case should always be **6** (5 characters + the newline character).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
  char line[50];

  printf("Give five digit number > ");

  if (fgets(line, 50, stdin))
  {
    size_t len = strlen(line);

    if (len == 6) /* string is 5 characters long + \n fgets appends to the buffer */
    {
      if (isdigit((unsigned char)line[0]))
      {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
          printf("%c ", line[i]);
        }
      }
      else
      {
        /* handle first digit error */
      }
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I now see where the problem was and got the code running :) this has been bugging me for couple of days and your answer truly helped